# Javascript several keywords search

Tags: javascript

I need help to search several keywords for example "reduce" and "reduce more" and "decrease" and "top" in below javascript.
I tried to make it like "if(text.search("reduce", "reduce", "reduce more")!=-1)" but doesnt work.

My code below:

```
macro ="CODE:";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT"+"\n";
iimPlay(macro)

var text=iimGetLastExtract();
if(text.search("reduce") != -1)
{
    error;
}
```

Comment: Try just `if (text.match(/reduce|more|reduce more/))` ... the pipe `|` means `OR`

Comment: Ok, so in my example if (text.match(/reduce|more|reduce more/) != -1) ?
I try...

Comment: No, without the `!=-1`

Answer (score 0):

Use regex:

`/reduce|reduce  more|decrease|top/.test(text)`

or construct regex with string pattern:

`new RegExp("reduce|reduce  more|decrease|top").test(text);`